# Exception thrown while calling scanner more than once. "Exception in thread main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found"

Tags: java

I am pretty new at Java and am just learning so please be kind.
I am doing a coding Inheritance challenge and I'm trying to use user inputs to set up a car before driving.
When I call the 2 methods I am using to set the parameters with Scanner this first method `testCar.drivingTest()` works fine, however when `testCar.carAgeType()` is called, I get an exception.

Below are the requests and inputs as well as the exception.

**Would you like to test a used car today? : y or n**

y

**great , do you have a driving licence :type: big, medium or small**

big

**Great you passed your 'big' exam. Lets check the MOT : type: pass or fail**

pass

**What type of car were you looking for :type: sports , town or 4X4**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found

at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1651)

at learning.java.Car.carAgeType(Car.java:30)

at learning.java.Main.main(Main.java:17)



Process finished with exit code 1
```

From what I can gather searching google most people use .hasNextLine() to check something but I don't know what to do or why this is coming back as false on testCar.carAgeType. both methods use basically the same code and when I call only one of the methods testCar.carAgeType or testCar.drivingTest they work fine when on there own but when called one after the other I get the exception. I am also unsure what to do when I use .hasNextLine and it comes back false.

Can anyone help me understand why Scanner throws an exception when it is called in multiple methods?
All help is much appreciated, thanks.

Code sample bellow has main and 2 classes, Vehicle parent and car child

```
import java.util.Scanner;
 
public class Main  {
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
 
        System.out.println("Would you like to test a used car today? : y or n");
 
        if ("y".equals(scanner.nextLine())){
 
            while (true) {
                Car testCar = new Car();
                testCar.drivingTest();
                testCar.carAgeType();
                break;
            }
        }else{
            System.out.println("dang");
        }
        scanner.close();
    }
    
}
 
 
 
 
import java.util.Scanner;
 
public class Vehicle {
    private String licence, MOT;
 
    public Vehicle(){
        this("null", "null");
    }
 
    public Vehicle(String licence, String MOT) {
        this.licence = licence;
        this.MOT = MOT;
    }
 
    public String getLicence() {
        return licence;
    }
 
    public String getMOT() {
        return MOT;
    }
 
 
 
    public void drivingTest(){
        Scanner DTScan = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("great , do you have a driving licence :type: big, medium or small");
 
            String reply = DTScan.nextLine();
            if ("big".equals(reply) || "medium".equals(reply) || "small".equals(reply)) {
                this.licence = reply;
            } else {
                this.licence = "fail";
            }
            System.out.println("Great you passed your '" + licence + "' exam. Lets check the MOT : type: pass or fail");
            reply = DTScan.nextLine();
            if ("pass".equals(reply) || "fail".equals(reply)) {
                this.MOT = reply;
            } else {
                this.MOT = "invalid";
            }
        DTScan.close();
    }
 
}
 
 
 
 
import java.util.Scanner;
 
public class Car extends Vehicle{
private String type;
private int age;
 
    public Car(){
    }
 
    public Car(String licence, String MOT, String type, int age) {
        super(licence, MOT);
        this.type = type;
        this.age = age;
    }
 
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
 
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
 
    public void carAgeType(){
        Scanner ATScan = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("What type of car were you looking for :type: sports , town or 4X4");
 
          ATScan.nextLine();
          String reply = ATScan.nextLine();
          if ("sports".equals(reply) || "town".equals(reply) || "4X4".equals(reply)) {
              this.type = reply;
          } else {
              this.type = "invalid";
          }
          System.out.println("And what sort of Age :type: between 1 and 10");
          int years = ATScan.nextInt();
          if (years > 0 && years < 10) {
              this.age = years;
          } else {
              this.age = -1;
          }
 
        ATScan.close();
 
    }
 
 
}
```

Comment: `while (true) {` and then unconditionally `break`? Please, remove it. It serves no purpose.

Comment: You should also follow the Java Naming Conventions: variable names and method names are written in camelCase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Main34 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Would you like to test a used car today? : y or n");
        String val = scanner.nextLine();
        if ("y".equals(val)) {

            while (true) {
                Car testCar = new Car();
                testCar.drivingTest(scanner);
                testCar.carAgeType(scanner);
                break;
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("dang");
        }
        scanner.close();
    }

}


class Vehicle {
    private String licence, MOT;

    public Vehicle() {
        this("null", "null");
    }

    public Vehicle(String licence, String MOT) {
        this.licence = licence;
        this.MOT = MOT;
    }

    public String getLicence() {
        return licence;
    }

    public String getMOT() {
        return MOT;
    }


    public void drivingTest(Scanner scanner) {
        System.out.println("great , do you have a driving licence :type: big, medium or small");

        String reply = scanner.nextLine();
        if ("big".equals(reply) || "medium".equals(reply) || "small".equals(reply)) {
            this.licence = reply;
        } else {
            this.licence = "fail";
        }
        System.out.println("Great you passed your '" + licence + "' exam. Lets check the MOT : type: pass or fail");
        reply = scanner.nextLine();
        if ("pass".equals(reply) || "fail".equals(reply)) {
            this.MOT = reply;
        } else {
            this.MOT = "invalid";
        }
    }
}


class Car extends Vehicle {
    private String type;
    private int age;

    public Car() {
    }

    public Car(String licence, String MOT, String type, int age) {
        super(licence, MOT);
        this.type = type;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void carAgeType(Scanner scanner) {
        System.out.println("Enter age");
        System.out.println("What type of car were you looking for :type: sports , town or 4X4");
        String reply = scanner.next();
        if ("sports".equals(reply) || "town".equals(reply) || "4X4".equals(reply)) {
            this.type = reply;
        } else {
            this.type = "invalid";
        }
        System.out.println("And what sort of Age :type: between 1 and 10");
        int years = scanner.nextInt();
        if (years > 0 && years < 10) {
            this.age = years;
        } else {
            this.age = -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of creating Scanner object for every call, you just need to pass your existing scanner object to method.

Also instead of directly checking **`if ("y".equals(scanner.nextLine()))`**  , you need to check using some variable like this **`if ("y".equals(val))`**

Try above code, it will work fine.

Comment: Thank you, i wasnt sure how to call/reuse the scanner from the other class. i knew there would be a simple answer but im only just at the beginning of my class.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Oracle documentation on the Scanner class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#close()):

> When a Scanner is closed, it will close its input source if the source implements the Closeable interface.

This means that when your first method closes the scanner, it closes also the input (System.in) and that's why you get the exception and also why calling only one method doesn't throw the exception.

Just close only the first scanner you have in your main and it should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the fact that you use `Scanner` with `System.in` (which is a static `InputStream`). Whenever you call `close()` on a `Scanner`, it will automatically close the underlying `InputStream`, in this case `System.in`. Once `System.in` is closed, no other `Scanner` can read from it.

The solution to that problem is to don't close the `Scanner` in each of the functions and only do that in the `main` method.